# How to find an array from parent array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using below code to find an array inside parent array but it is not working that is retuning empty even though the specified key exits in the parent array

```
$cards_parent = $feedData['BetradarLivescoreData']['Sport']['Category']['Tournament']['Match'];
$cards = array();

foreach($cards_parent as $key => $card)
{
    if ($key === 'Cards')
    {
        $cards[] = $cards_parent[$key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Do you know any array function that will search parent array for specified key and if found it will create an array starting from that key?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your example what the issue is. Give a sample of what `$cards_parent` might look like. If you mean the key is at an unknown depth within the array, look into recursive iteration.

Comment: Why is `$cards` an array? It seems that it will hold only one value anyway...

Answer (score 1):

you want [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists)

takes in a needle (string), then haystack (array) and returns true or false.

in one of the comments, there is a recursive solution that looks like it might be more like what you want. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#94601

Answer (score 1):

here you can use recursion:

```
function Recursor($arr)
{
 if(is_array($arr))
 {
  foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
  {
   if($k == 'Cards')
   {
     $_GLOBAL['cards'][] = $card;
   } else {
     Recursor($arr[$k]);
   }
  }
 }
}

$cards_parent = $feedData['BetradarLivescoreData']['Sport']['Category']['Tournament']['Match'];
$_GLOBAL['cards'] = array();
Recursor($cards_parent);
```

Comment: Uuuuh, `$_GLOBAL`... >_< You should really `return` instead.

Comment: No. I shouldn`t. I need to pass all array. If return - recursion will be interrupted. $_Global is here to rememder finded values and to go to the end of array.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to return and merge values throughout recursive calls. All your recursive invocations return implicitly anyway. At least use a static variable if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please put a `print_r($feedData)` up? I ran the below code

```
<?php
 $feedData = array('BetradarLivescoreData' => array('Sport' => array('Category' => array('Tournament' => array('Match' => array('Cards' => array('hellow','jwalk')))))));
 $cards_parent = $feedData['BetradarLivescoreData']['Sport']['Category']['Tournament']['Match'];
$cards = array();

 foreach($cards_parent as $key => $card)
 {
     if ($key === 'Cards')
     {
         $cards[] = $card;
         break;
     }
 }
 print_r($cards);
```

And it returned a populated array:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => hellow [1] => jwalk ) )

So your code is correct, it may be that your array $feedData is not.